# Run NUnit tests in C# while other project is being debugged

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I don't even know if it's possible to do this.

I need to run some NUnit tests while other project in the same solution is running in debug mode with an application's process active (AutoCAD).

Or maybe the other project should be run in debug mode when I click the button to run the tests... Both options would do it.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @devNull I tried executing the tests when the project is run but visual studio disables the option to run tests.

I haven't found a way to start a project in debug mode when another project is run.

Comment: if you're running "unit tests", why do you need something else to run at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

When you run a mstest unit test the test created its own application scope. Unless you are able to somehow initiate you entire application in a test (not sure it is a good idea) you should take a look at using a remote debugger (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019)